# A word that implies 'unique' (on an object or act)

Tags: adjectives

First time posting here, no idea if this is the right sort of question but I'll give the full background and let you decide.

I play a game called DotA, in which there are items which modify the way in which you attack. In some instance, they weaken the enemy so they take extra damage, in other instances they stun the enemy. These items are labelled

`unique attack modifier`

I believe this phrase to be somewhat incorrect for its intended use. It's supposed to imply that the items cannot be used in conjunction with one another, thus an implication that it must be unique, not a statement that it is. Some of the items are very similar in their effect, however they are all technically unique in that no two are the same. It's not quite right though, the intention is that the items cannot be used in conjunction with another that has the label.

Can anyone advise on what the right word would be to go here?

Also, please excuse if my tagging is a bit iffy, I know very little English theory, in spite of it being my native language and what not.

Thanks

Comment: You could call it the **active** modifier - I think that suggests that only one can be in operation at a time.

Comment: _Dedicated:_ exclusively allocated to or intended for a particular purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only one can be used at a time, they are **exclusive**.  Using [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exclusive), meaning 2a:

> 1 a :  excluding or having power to exclude
>
> b :  limiting or limited
>   to possession, control, or use by a single individual or group
>
> **2 a :  excluding others from participation**
>
> b :  snobbishly aloof